# Receiving PubSub notifications through IM client

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I am new to Openfire and XMPP and there are a few things that are a bit unclear to me.

I would like to use pubsub to notify all the subscribers when new blog post is published on the website. Subscribers should be able to receive these notifications through their IM applications of choice (Adium for example). The problem is that the received notification is something like this:

```
<message from='pubsub.shakespeare.lit' to='francisco@denmark.lit' id='foo'>
  <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
    <items node='princely_musings'>
      <item id='ae890ac52d0df67ed7cfdf51b644e901'>
        [ ... ENTRY ... ]
      </item>
    </items>
  </event>
</message>
```

which regular clients can not interpret. Im I supposed to transfer this type of message to something an IM client can understand, preferably a chat message? Should this be added as an extra functionality as a server plugin, or is there some other way? Are there any example implementations of something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your [ENTRY] is going to consist of XML markup that you'll want to do something with before you show it to a user. You'll need to write a plugin for the target client that knows what schema to expect for that node and how to render it.

If you just want plain text, consider using [MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html).